# How to find a point where a circumference intersects with an ellipse in 2D (C#)

Tags: c#

I need to find a point where a circumference intersects an ellipse.

Equation of ellipse is:

```
((x-x1)^2)/(a*a)+((y-y1)^2)/(b*b)=1
```

Equation of circumference is:

```
(x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2=r*r
```

, where (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) - are the figure's centers.

I've been trying to find (x, y) of intersection using these formula's above, but stuck.

Further, I've tried to find something in google on this topic. Google answered me with several solutions but all of them were far from logical complete.

If someone already solve this problem Please Help.

Comment: You will probably get a better answer on math.stackexchange.com http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Do you mean 'circle' when you say ['circumference'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumference)?

Comment: Since a circle is an ellipse with a == b, if you solve this for two ellipses then you have the solution for a circle and an ellipse. [Here's a sample solution in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/11/see-where-two-ellipses-intersect-in-c-part-1/).

Comment: Do you mean 'circle' when you say 'circumference'? - Yes

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0zvu82):

```
public class Ellipse
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public double a { get; set; }
    public double b { get; set; }        
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var el1 = new Ellipse { x = 10, y = 4, a = 5, b = 2 };
        var el2 = new Ellipse { x = 9, y = 4, a = 2, b = 3 };

        var Xmin = Math.Max(el1.x - el1.a, el2.x - el2.a);
        var Xmax = Math.Min(el1.x + el1.a, el2.x + el2.a);

        var step = 0.01;
        var accuracy = 0.01;

        Func<Ellipse, double, List<double>> calculateY = (el, x) => {
            var shift = el.b * Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow((x - el.x) / el.a, 2));
            return new List<double> { el.y - shift, el.y + shift };
        };

        var result = new List<List<double>>();

        for(double i = Xmin; i <= Xmax; i += step)
        {
            var left = calculateY(el1, i);
            var right = calculateY(el2, i);

            foreach(var l in left)
                foreach (var r in right)                        
                    if(Math.Abs(l - r) < accuracy)
                        result.Add(new List<double> { i, (l + r) / 2 });                                           
        }

        foreach(var res in result)            
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("x = {0}, y = {1}", res.First(), res.Last()));            
    }        
}
```